# DRF Class based view api data filtering issue

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add Update and Destroy view to this view. But the problem is I know how to do that with function-based view and I'm using here class-based.

`views.py`

```py
class UpdatePostView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'id'
```

`serializers.py`

```py
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Problem 1:** Any user can delete or update any post from other users

**Problem 2:** In update method there is an option to update user

```json
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Post 1",
    "image": null,
    "user": 3
}
```

I'm trying to keep these views as class based view as I can to reduce code lines

Answer (score 1):

We can override the `get_queryset` instead of `queryset = Post.objects.all()`.

In UpdatePostView class

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Post.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

or keep using `queryset=`

```
queryset = Post.objects.all()

def get_queryset(self):
    return super().get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)
```

So, only can access their post.

Comment: Thanks, one line of code just fixed my whole issue